# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request

Tags: firebase, cors, google-cloud-functions

I am using vue and express + firebase function for backend but it keep giving me this error. I deploy my firebase function and using localhost to access my server. Can anyone help? Thanks!

> from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
>   Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

frontend

```
        let updateWorkshop = Firebase.functions().httpsCallable('v3/update/workshop');
        updateWorkshop()
          .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            commit('setInfoMsg', processResults (res.body.results))
            commit('setError', null)
            commit('setLoading', false)
          }, err => {
            console.log(err);
            commit('setError', processResults (err.body.results))
            commit('setLoading', false)
          })
```

backend

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const app = require('express')();
const cors = require('cors');
const colors = require('colors');

const UPDATE_WORKSHOP_DATE = require('./src/update-workshop');

// Automatically allow cross-origin requests
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

const asyncMiddleware = fn => (req, res, next) => {
    Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next))
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            res.json(err)
        })
        .catch(next)
};

app.get('/v3/update/workshop', asyncMiddleware( async (req, res, next) => {
    let results = await UPDATE_WORKSHOP_DATE.Run()
    res.status(200).json({results: results})
}))

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Well, I figured out the problem I was having, for one. Makes the bounty a bit pointless. I had accidentally failed to deploy my cloud function-- there was nothing listed in the firebase cloud functions console. Ultimate facepalm!

Answer (score -1):

need to add the "api" into the url as well.

Firebase.functions().httpsCallable('api/v3/update/workshop');